# Как найти все sparse-файлы на диске?

Tags: .net, windows, файлы, ntfs

Надо найти все [sparse-файлы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB) на диске с файловой системой ntfs.

Устраивает как уже существующая программа, так и код проверки на то, является ли файл разряженным. Не смог найти нужную функцию в C#. Если есть решение под линукс, то тоже пойдёт, хотя под windows более желательно.

PS: [Связанный вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/736944/178988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .NET это свойство находится в **атрибутах** файла, кои [представляются `System.IO.FileAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes(v=vs.110).aspx). Конкретно на разреженность указывает бит `SparseFile`.

Немножко переработав приведённый в MSDN пример, можно получить код проверки файла на разреженность:

```
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes("c:/Temp/testfile.txt");
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.SparseFile) == FileAttributes.SparseFile)
{
    Console.WriteLine("sparse");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not sparse");
}
```